# jsonObject is a string - how to convert to json?

Tags: javascript, string, json

I have a weird problem with one of my ajax submitted forms … I have a file-upload in the form and somehow a valid JSON Object from the server is now a String …

```
if (typeof jsonObject == 'string')
        console.log('yes, it's a string'); //yes, it's a string

console.log(jsonObject); // { "status":"success", "data":"Updated profile successfully"}
```

So, without the file-upload and the `enctype:multipart` in the form `console.log(jsonObject)` is returning `>Object` with a "success" and "data" attribute. With the file-upload in the form somehow the jsonObject is a string like you can see above.

Any ideas what could cause that? Or how can I convert the string back to a valid JSON object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JSON only exists in JavaScript as a string... so your request is a bit confusing. I assume you want a *JavaScript* object.

Comment: Yes, you're right, didn't exactly know the difference. I need a jsObject - correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I convert the string back to a valid [..] object?

```
jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
```

Comment: That does not result in a JSON object (whatever that is) but in a JavaScript object.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that's what he meant.

Comment: Yes, me too, but it should be clarified and explained that JSON is not JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference, but @JamesMcLaughlin was right - that's what I meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You run it through [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON), while using [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to provide that method for older browsers.

```
var js_object = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

(And that will give you a JavaScript object, since there [is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)).

If you are already using jQuery, then it has its own abstraction method — [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) — that you can use instead of json2.js. It is an excessively large library to load just for that feature though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse which will only work in new version of browser(will not work in IE7-) or you can use $jQuery.parseJSON

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/